# Fixing No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting this problem. Spring security 3.1.3.RELEASEE. This is a simple Spring form based login security. I am getting an exception No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined whenever the server is getting started.

```
WEB.XML -

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml, 
                /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/login-security.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

LOGIN--SECURITY.XML -

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

I do not get any warnings either. Can somebody please have a look ?
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DelegatingFilterProxy` only has access to the, so called, root application context. Which is the file loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.

So instead of letting the `DispatcherServlet` load the `/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/login-security.xml` move it to the configuration of the `ContextLoaderListener`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/login-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks Denium. I just imported my login-security.xml in root-context.xml and it worked